# make an input field required in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I know there is a way in plain html to require the field have some kind of value. I believe it's 'input required'.
However, I'm not sure how to accomplish this in ember using handlebars. I've tried this but it was unsuccessful:

```
{{input required value=tax class="form-control" placeholder="State Tax"}}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ember input helpers you always have to give values to attributes. The shourtcuts like `<input disabled required value="..."/>` in html without value are not allowed in handlebars. Instead you have to write `{{input disabled=true required=true value="..."/>`

See ember twiddle with your example: https://ember-twiddle.com/b073b4551065e8884056de55fe0c9800?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C